# Do most hats only make you look fancy?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

There are some headgear (and same goes for robes/cloaks) that have special attributes that benefit the wearer of such objects.

Most hats, however, have no special description. Do hats/helmets/etc give any bonus at all, if not explicitly mentioned in the item's description?

Comment: Well, with enchanting they look fancy AND give obvious benefits.

Comment: @Deltharis except that you can't enchant hats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast majority of hats/helmets give you no bonus at all, and they cannot be enchanted to give a bonus. They are purely decorative.

There are some magic hats/helmets that do give a bonus, but they are not very common.

If they do give a bonus, this certainly will be listed in the item description.